# Quero agrupar 3 colunas em apenas uma, separadas por vírgula no R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Meu conjunto de dados é assim:

```
    x   y   z
A 1.1 1.2 1.3
B 2.1 2.2 2.3
```

Usando o R, quero agrupar as 3 colunas em apenas uma, separadas por vírgula.
Quero que fique assim:

```
              x   
A 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
B 2.1, 2.2, 2.3
```

---

### Dados

```
dados <-
structure(list(x = c(1.1, 2.1), y = c(1.2, 2.2), z = c(1.3, 2.3
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", "B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `unite`:

```
library(tidyr)

unite(data = dados, col = x, c(x, y, z), sep = ", ")

#                x
#  A 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
#  B 2.1, 2.2, 2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução R base com `apply`.

```
dados[[1]] <- apply(dados, 1, paste, collapse = ", ")
dados <- dados[1]

dados
#              x
#A 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
#B 2.1, 2.2, 2.3
```

---

### Dados

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
    x   y   z
A 1.1 1.2 1.3
B 2.1 2.2 2.3
", header = TRUE)
```